# How to test puppeteer page.evaluate() in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

Learning puppeteer. How can i test commands out without having to run puppeteer?

For example, I tried to run the command in chrome's javascript console:

```
const is_disabled = await page.$('button[disabled]') !== null;
```

It doesn't work:

```
caught (in promise) ReferenceError: page is not defined ReferenceError: page is not defined
```

Comment: Chrome and Puppeteer are different things. Chromium is a browser, Puppeteer uses the browser to create their own api. You cannot have puppeteer stuff on chromium just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the documentation to see what each function does. For example, the docs of the [page.$](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageselector) says:

> The method runs `document.querySelector` within the page. If no element matches the selector, the return value resolves to `null`.

That means it runs [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) inside the page, which you can also do yourself in the Developer console like this:

```
document.querySelector('button[disabled]') !== null
```